# How to dereference pointer when pointee value assigned in response

Tags: c++, pointers, exchangewebservices, dereference, gsoap

I want to  dereference a pointer `firsm->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView` which takes value, when response is arrived.

```
ns1__MessageType* messgT = new ns1__MessageType();
std::vector<ns1__MessageType> v;
int count;

ews__FindItemResponseMessageType *firsm = new ews__FindItemResponseMessageType();
firsm->RootFolder = new ns1__FindItemParentType();
count = *firsm->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView;

for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
    v.push_back(messgT[i]);
    std::cout << "Hello"  << std::endl;
}
```

`TotalItemsInView` is defined in class of `ns1__FindItemParentType`.

```
class ns1__FindItemParentType
{ public:
       int* TotalItemsInView ;
};
```

Here the `TotalItemsInView` will have integer value in response of SOAP request. I want to use that integer value in count to run the 'for loop' that many times.

In compilation I've got `Segmentation fault` may be because of Empty value at `TotalItemsInView`, but in response it will have value, so how can i do that. I'm new to pointers, Any help appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:
My XML Received log:

```
<m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
            <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:RootFolder TotalItemsInView="2" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
                <t:Items>
                    <t:Message>
                        <t:ItemId Id="b30rTZMma5" ChangeKey="CQAAABAAAAAWl"/>
                    </t:Message>
                    <t:Message>
                        <t:ItemId Id="tNFsAAAIFUA" ChangeKey="CQAAAAAAWT"/>
                    </t:Message>
                </t:Items>
            </m:RootFolder>
        </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
    </m:ResponseMessages>
</m:FindItemResponse>
```

Comment: And how does `ns1__FindItemParentType` constructor look like?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall there is no constructor in class, but there is some comments i.e. `
 class ns1__FindItemParentType operations:
 soap_new_ns1__FindItemParentType(soap*) allocate
 soap_new_ns1__FindItemParentType(soap*, int num) allocate array
soap_new_req_ns1__FindItemParentType(soap*, ...) allocate, set required members
 soap_new_set_ns1__FindItemParentType(soap*, ...) allocate, set all public members
 int soap_read_ns1__FindItemParentType(soap*, ns1__FindItemParentType*) deserialize from a stream
 int soap_write_ns1__FindItemParentType(soap, ns1__FindItemParentType*) serialize to a stream`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I don't know behind the scenes how SOAP works, but hope that comments are helpful to you to understand the idea.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "when response is arrived"? As it is now, you are dereferencing an unitialised `TotalItemsInView` pointer, and getting undefined behaviour. It seems like this pointer should be assigned after the response arrived? If so, you should move the code that uses this pointer somewhere else.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I've my code on the location, when response is arrived and present in XML format Received log. For Received XML log see my UPDATE section above, from where i want  to extract the value of `TotalItemsInView` .

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Is there any other way to do that, I want to dereference it just because to use the count value in 'For loop'. I've tried with `int* count = firsm->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView;` but this give `Segmentation fault` in for loop `for(int i = 0; i< *count; i++)` this is in dereferencing `*count`

Comment: The problem is not that you are dereferencing it wrong, it's fine. The problem is that it is not initialized, so when you are dereferencing `count`, you are dereferencing some garbage pointer. You should assign the value of that pointer somewhere inbetween these lines: `firsm->RootFolder = new ns1__FindItemParentType();
count = *firsm->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView;`. Apparently you need to do something like `firsm->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView = response.GetResponseValue()` where `GetResponseValue()` should extract the value from the XML

Comment: When someone asks you for information that's not present in your question, please answer by **editing the question, not commenting on it!!**

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall This XML code which is written above, is not generated as file separately, rather generates in Received log file, so how can i access this? thank you.

Comment: I've found this from official documentation- The serializers and deserializers can be found in the generated soapC.cpp file. These serializers and deserializers can be used separately by an application without the need to build a full client or service application. This is useful for applications that need to save or export their data in XML or need to import or load data stored in XML format. @SingerOfTheFall Thank you for help.

Comment: @funGeek, well, I didn't do much, but you welcome. If your problem is now solved, don't hesitate to post an answer yourself and accept it, so people who face the similar problem later can found it.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Actually it's not solve yet. whenever it'll solved i'll do that. I was thanked to you, for that much help to think me about this problem in right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong here at `firsm->RootFolder = new ns1__FindItemParentType()` where i tried to initialize a response structure with empty value, that's way i've problem in derefrencing it.
So thr right way to do so is

```
ews__FindItemResponseMessageType *firsm = new ews__FindItemResponseMessageType();
firsm = findItemRes.ews__FindItemResponse->ResponseMessages->__union_ArrayOfResponseMessagesType->union_ArrayOfResponseMessagesType.FindItemResponseMessage;
count = *firsm->RootFolder->TotalItemsInView;
```